# How to join two tables without messing up the query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query for example (good, it works how I want it to)

```
SELECT  `discusComments`.`memberID`, COUNT( `discusComments`.`memberID`) AS postcount 
FROM `discusComments`
GROUP BY  `discusComments`.`memberID` ORDER BY postcount DESC
```

Example Results:

```
memberid    postcount
3             283
6             230
9             198
```

Now I want to join the memberid of the discusComments table with that of the discusTopic table (because what I really want to do is only get my results from a specific GROUP, and the group id is only in the topic table and not in the comment one hence the join.

```
SELECT  `discusComments`.`memberID`, COUNT( `discusComments`.`memberID`) AS postcount 
FROM `discusComments`
LEFT JOIN `discusTopics` ON `discusComments`.`memberID` =  `discusTopics`.`memberID`
GROUP BY  `discusComments`.`memberID` ORDER BY postcount DESC
```

Example Results:

```
memberid    postcount
3             14789
6              8678
9              6987
```

How can I stop this huge increase happening in the postcount? I need to preserve it as before.

Once I have this sorted I want to have some kind of line which says `WHERE discusTopics.groupID = 6`, for example

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `discusComments` (
  `id` bigint(255) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `topicID` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `timeStamp` bigint(12) NOT NULL,
  `memberID` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
  `thumbsUp` int(15) NOT NULL default '0',
  `thumbsDown` int(15) NOT NULL default '0',
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL default '1',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7190 ;
```

.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `discusTopics` (
  `id` bigint(255) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `groupID` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
  `memberID` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `views` bigint(255) NOT NULL default '0',
  `lastUpdated` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `groupID` (`groupID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=913 ;
```

Comment: Are the tables `discusComments` and `discusTopics` related to each other in any way other than by `MemberID`? Maybe the join condition you are using is just wrong (or incomplete).

Comment: You need to explain more about the tables and their relationships.  It seems clear to me that each `memberID` has many records in the `discusTopics` table.  But why, what does that table mean?  And what are it's foreign keys and unique constraints.  You mention that the table has a `groupID` field.  Is `memberID, groupID` unique?  If so, include `groupID` in your select an `GROUP BY` and see what you get.

Comment: I've just added the structures

Comment: Looks like `discusComments.TopicID = discusTopics.id` would be a better choice for your join condition. But you are not explaining much, so I can't be sure.

Comment: Basically im looking how how many posts a member has made in total (from the comments table) in a specific GROUP, and to get this group id, it has to be taken from the TOPIC table

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  `discusComments`.`memberID`, COUNT( `discusComments`.`memberID`) AS postcount 
FROM `discusComments`
JOIN `discusTopics` ON `discusComments`.`topicID` =  `discusTopics`.`id`
GROUP BY  `discusComments`.`memberID` ORDER BY postcount DESC
```

Joining  the topicid in both tables solved the memberID issue.  Thanks @Andiry M

Answer (score 0):

You need to use just JOIN not LEFT JOIN and you can add AND discusTopics.memberID = 6 after ON `discusComments`.`memberID` =  `discusTopics`.`memberID`

You can use subqueries lik this

```
SELECT  `discusComments`.`memberID`, COUNT( `discusComments`.`memberID`) AS postcount 
FROM `discusComments` where `discusComments`.`memberID` in 
(select distinct  memberid from `discusTopics` WHERE GROUPID = 6)
```

Comment: im still getting a ridiculously large postcount when joining

Comment: try using count(distinct  `discusComments`.`memberID`)

Comment: just worked out that the sql is somehow doing the amount of times the memberID appears in one table multiplied by the amount of times the memberID appears in the other!

Comment: Yes it the purpose of a join, it takes rows from 2 tables and make it into a single view, if you have multiple enteries in one you will see numbers of rows equal that number

Comment: I mean, i only want to count the number of times the memberID appears in discusComments, not in both tables multiplied together!

Comment: can you add in WHERE GROUPID = 6 ?

Comment: I still get the memerID count from discusTopic and discusComments multiplied together

Answer (score -1):

If i understand your question right you do not need to use JOIN here at all. JOINs are needed in case when you have many to many relationships and you need for each value in one table select all corresponding values in another table.

But here you have many to one relationship if i got it right. Then you can simply do select from two tables like this

```
SELECT a.*, b.id FROM a, b WHERE a.pid = b.id
```

This is simple request and won't create a giant overhead as JOIN does

PS: In the future try to experiment with your queries, try to avoid JOINs especially in MySQL. They are slow and dangerous in their complexity. For 90% of cases when you want to use JOIN there is simple and much faster solution.

Comment: You may well be understanding the question right, but you definitely seem to have a misconception about joins. What is the overhead you have mentioned? And do you realise that your answer uses a join, even though it doesn't use the `JOIN` keyword?

Comment: @AndriyM It does not use JOIN at all. Please refer to MySQL interpreter documentation to see how multitable queries are working. And yes, JOINs are creating big overhead on queries. You can try yourself by creating (for example) simple php script with 10 JOINs against 10 multitable queries.

Comment: im still getting a ridiculously large postcount when joining

Comment: @JakeStainer can you update original topic with `CREATE TABLE` statements, so we can see structure there and tell us more on relationships in this structure.

Comment: @AlexKey How can I get the create table statements from phpmyadmin?

Comment: @JakeStainer do export of specific table and untick the `export data` box

Comment: just worked out that the sql is somehow doing the amount of times the memberID appears in one table multiplied by the amount of times the memberID appears in the other! Thats what the big numbers amount to

Comment: @AlexKey, it is in fact using an implicit join which is a SQL antipattern. And joins do not create giant overhead where the join felds are indexed properly. Databases are optimized to use joins.